# Yii2 how to add regex validations in controller function

Tags: php, regex, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How to add regex configuration in my function .
I ant to allow all regex validations in my API during its check.

Here is my function.

```
public function actionViewBidHistory()
   {
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $msg = array();
    $request = Yii::$app->request;
    $headers = Yii::$app->request->headers;
    $authorization = $headers->get('Authorization');
    $msg["details"] = Bidding::BidHistoryDetails($authorization);
    return ($msg);
  }
```

Any help will really be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What input (request, in this case) are you expeting, and what output you want to get in response?

Comment: @wormi4ok thanks for responding my question . I want to use this array('fieldname', 'pattern'=>'/^[\w\-\_\'\,]+$/'); kind of thing in which any pattern can be used . Now what i am facing problem is " ' " this kind of regex arn't being taken by my API it throws error.

Comment: sorry, still don't get what are you trying to do. Add a code example to your question, which will more or less, do what you want.